# MySQL count types per day

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a table

```
| date | name | type |
```

I want to transform the data to make a table that counts how many names of each type appeared on each date.

```
| date | count(type_a) | count(type_b) | ....
```

I had two types, so I did this

```
SELECT t0.date, type_a, type_b 
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT date from my_table) AS t0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date, COUNT(name) AS type_a
           FROM my_table
           WHERE type='type_a'
           GROUP BY date) AS t1
    ON t0.date = t1.date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date, COUNT(name) AS type_b
           FROM my_table
           WHERE type='type_b'
           GROUP BY date) AS t2 
    ON t0.date = t2.date
```

But I feel like this is an overkill, and becomes too repetitive for more types.

So let's say I have 4 types. I'm sure there is something nicer I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally aggregate w/ a case statement:

```
select date,
       sum(case when type = 'type_a' then 1 else 0 end) as type_a,
       sum(case when type = 'type_b' then 1 else 0 end) as type_b
from   tbl
group by date
```

Add additional case statements for additional types.

The above shows zeros for dates w/ no type a or type b values, which matches the logic of your outer joins. If you didn't want such dates at all you could add this where clause:

```
where  type in ('type_a','type_b')
```

Comment: thanks! is there some solution for the case when I have too many types to do it manually like this?

Comment: @AndreiIvanov not a purely sql solution, whenever your expected columns depend on the output you have to rely on dynamic sql